# Weak derivative of a Lipschitz function

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $f \in C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R})^*$ be a distribution. How can I show the following: $$f \in C^{0,1}(\mathbb{R}) \Leftrightarrow f \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \text{ and } f' \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R}) \text{.}$$
Here $C^{0,1}(\mathbb{R})$ is the space of bounded Lipschitz functions on $\mathbb{R}$ and $f'$ is the distributional derivative of $f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, suppose that $f$ is a bounded Lipschitz function (hence in $L^\infty$).  Then $f$ is absolutely continuous and you have $f(x) - f(a) = \int_a^x f^{'} (t)dt$.  The Lipschitz condition gives that there is a constant $L$ so that $|\int_a^x f^{'} (t)dt| \leq L(x-a)$.  Dividing by $(x-a)$ and applying the Lebesgue differentiation theorem gives that $|f^{'} (t)| \leq L$ almost everywhere.

Conversely, suppose that $f \in L^\infty$ and $f^{'} \in L^\infty$ as distributions.  It suffices now to show that $f(x)$ differs by a single constant almost everywhere from the Lipschitz function $\int_0^x f^{'} (t)dt$, so view $\int_0^x f^{'} (t)dt$ as another candidate distribution.  An elementary exercise (which is pretty standard) shows that two distributions which have the same distributional derivative differ by a constant and so the result follows.

Comment: Does $f' \in L^\infty$ as a distributions mean that there exist $g\in L^\infty$ such that for every test function $\phi \in C^\infty_c$, $(f',\phi)=(g,\phi)$?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\int_0^\infty f'(t) dt$, when I only know $f' \in L^\infty$ as a distribution?

Comment: @Cantor Yes, $f^{'} = g \in L^\infty$ means that there is an actual function so that $ \langle f, \varphi^{'} \rangle = - \langle g, \varphi \rangle$.  It doesn't make sense to talk about distributions living in function spaces unless you mean that there is an actual function which agrees with the distribution on all test functions.